# How to use Except linq query in c#, MVC Validations

Tags: c#, linq, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code to set a validation on `date and time` box in mvc .

```
public class GetCallBackValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string Feed = "Note Interested";

        //return value != null && (DateTime)value > DateTime.Now;
        Models.YelloAdminDbContext db = new Models.YelloAdminDbContext();
        var temp = db.SaveFeedBack.Select(x => x.feedback.FeedBackDrpDown.Except(Feed));
        if (temp != null)
        {
            return value != null && (DateTime)value > DateTime.Now;
        }
        else return value == null;
    }
}
```

My question is

Am i using the right query? or what will be the better way?

second is this the right way to do validations in MVC?

Comment: what type of validations do u want on your dateandtime box....?

Comment: I have a drop down box at the top of page. I want that if the value in drop down box is any value except not interested then the user has to fill the callbackdate box

Comment: u can do this easily with javascript or jquery sir...

Comment: I am new call u guide me or give me any links .

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/